# Ignite's Merge SQL Does Not Insert New Row When Used with Nested Select

Tags: sql, ignite

When Merge SQL is used with nested Select, Merge does not handle aggregation correctly for new rows. For example, the table is

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
  key1 int  PRIMARY key,
  Name varCHAR(52),
  count int
) WITH "template=REPLICATED, backups=0, CACHE_NAME=Test1";
```

To merge new and existing rows, the following Merge SQL is used because it is not known which rows already exist or not. This type of merge / upsert is typical for count aggregation use cases.

```sql
MERGE INTO Test1(key1, name, count) VALUES
  (1, 'aaa', 500 + (SELECT count  FROM Test1 WHERE KEY1 = 1)),
  (2, 'bbb', 700 + (SELECT count  FROM Test1 WHERE KEY1 = 2)),
   ...
  (1000, 'zzz', 350 + (SELECT count  FROM Test1 WHERE KEY1 = 1000)),
```

However, for new rows, Merge stores NULL for count instead of the specified count values.  This type of aggregation on the values of a column is typical for merge / upsert for aggregation use cases. I also tried to use casewhen and ifnull on the nested select clause, but neither one resolves the issue. Is there a work-around solution for this Merge's issue ?

Also, if there is such a work-around solution, the use of nested select in Merge per row would cause the SQL string to be very long for doing Merge for mass number of rows, which is also typical for upsert operation. Does Ignite Merge have a short-hand SQL version similar to what MemSql provides for the entire SQL string rather than per individual row as in

```sql
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count  = count  + VALUES(count)
```

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `COALESCE()`?

```
(1, 'aaa', 500 + COALESCE((SELECT count  FROM Test1 WHERE KEY1 = 1), 0)),
```